# how to get latlong of google map inside a <script> from a website using beautiful soup

Tags: python

I have this website that tracks buses http://transitweb2/bus/track?type=BUS&Id=4342&date=2020-01-30&hour=18&minute=23&durr=15 and I would like to get their geocodes at a certain time and day. How can I get the latlong which is located at a  tag. But I also want only want to get the first script tag then move on to the next bus

In case the link won't open, I copy pasted the output I was able to get

```
import pandas as pd    
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.read_csv('W://tires.csv')
df = df.head(1)
for i in df.itertuples():
    url = f'http://transitweb2/bus/track?type=BUS&Id={i.bus_num}&date={i.date}&hour={i.hour}&minute={i.minute}&durr=15'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    print (all_scripts)
```

```
<script>
            //Set Map Options
            var opt = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.89982120,-87.62405420),
                    //adjust zoom level for ONEROUTE maps
                    zoom: 16,//<%=strZoomLevel%>,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    scrollwheel: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                                            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID],
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    //map.addControl(new ExtMapTypeControl({showTraffic: true, showTrafficKey: true}));  //Add Traffic Button
                    navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL },
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var mobj = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mobj);
                addRailLines(map);
                map.setOptions(opt);
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                    if (map.getZoom() > 19) { map.setZoom(19); }  //Min Zoom in
                    if (map.getZoom() < 12) { map.setZoom(12); }  //Max Zoom out
                });
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(41.89982120,-87.62405420));
    </script>, <script>
createMapMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(41.89982120,-87.62405420),"/Content/arrow/yellow/358.png","1/30/2020 6:25:00 PM","<b>18:25</b> Route: <b>146</b> Dir: <b>N</b><br> Run: <a href=/rtbm/schedule?run=P615> P615 </a> O/B: 56649 Bus: 4342<br> Speed: 0 Dev: 11<br> Last Trip Start: 01-30 18:01:01",null,8,"18:25");
```

Comment: Is the URL in your question correct? Clicking on it results in "Page not found"

Comment: It's working fine for me, maybe because it's an internal thing. but I posted a pic of the html

Comment: How do you think that you can get dynamic javascript variables from a string of javascript code?

Comment: I just want to get the first (41.89982120, -87.62405420) and ignore all the others

Comment: Then you can manipulate string.